# JAXB how to dynamically generate a schema to use it for validation immediately?

Tags: java, xml, validation, jaxb, xsd

I've spent a long time trying to figure out how to validate a XML file, and I've got it working with a pre-generated XSD schema. However, I wish to dynamically generate a schema without creating a file, based on the annotation class I have specified, I've tried to not specify any parameters to SchemaFactory, but then it seems to just create an empty schema (see comments below).

Here are the two classes I use for my JAXB reading and writing of a XML file.

This is the code for the class XMLTranslationWrapper:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)

@XmlRootElement(namespace = "my.package.namespace")
public class XMLTranslationWrapper {

      @XmlElementWrapper(name   = "TRANSLATIONS")
      @XmlElement(name          = "TRANSL")
      public ArrayList<XMLTranslationNode> translations;

      public XMLTranslationWrapper(){
          translations = new ArrayList<XMLTranslationNode>();
      }

      public void setTranslations(ArrayList<XMLTranslationNode> translations){
          this.translations = translations;
      }

      public XMLTranslationNode getTranslation(String code){
          for(XMLTranslationNode transl : translations){
              if(transl.getCode().equals(code))
                  return transl;
          }
        return null;
      }

      public void addTranslation(XMLTranslationNode translation){
          this.translations.add(translation);
      }
}
```

This is the code for the class XMLTranslationNode:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@XmlRootElement(name = "TRANSL")

@XmlType(propOrder = { "severity", "translation" })
public class XMLTranslationNode {

    private String severity;

    private String code;
    private String translation;

    @XmlElement(name="SEVERITY")
    public String getSeverity(){
        return this.severity;
    }

    public void setSeverity(String severity){
        this.severity = severity;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="CODE")
    public String getCode(){
        return this.code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code){
        this.code = code;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="TRANSLATION")
    public String getTranslation(){
        return this.translation;
    }

    public void setTranslation(String translation){
        this.translation = translation;
    }

}
```

This is the code I used to generate the pre-generated XSD schema:

```
public class generateSchema {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLTranslationWrapper.class);
            SchemaOutputResolver sor = new MySchemaOutputResolver();
            jaxbContext.generateSchema(sor);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class MySchemaOutputResolver extends SchemaOutputResolver {

        public Result createOutput(String namespaceURI, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
            File file = new File(suggestedFileName);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
            System.out.println(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
            result.setSystemId(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
            return result;
        }

    }

}
```

Finally here is a sample XML which can be used to test the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:xmlTranslationWrapper xmlns:ns2="my.package.namespace">
    <TRANSLATIONS>
        <TRANSL CODE="123">
            <SEVERITY>Information</SEVERITY>
            <TRANSLATION>ABC</TRANSLATION>
        </TRANSL>
    </TRANSLATIONS>
</ns2:xmlTranslationWrapper>
```

How can I dynamically generate my XSD schema without creating a file equivalent to using a pre-generated XSD schema?

Comment: What I'm puzzled with - why do you think schema factory will generate a schema for you "dynamically"? I think it just creates an empty schema instance so why do you expect it would validate anything?

Comment: @lexicore I did not read the documentation of the Schema Factory very well so I might've missunderstood it all. IF that is the case, how would I go on about doing it dynamically? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so the question reduces to the following: how would you generate the schema dynamically an use it for validation immediately. Correct? Please update the question. It is possible, I'll answer then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As promised. The idea is simple:

- First generate your schema into a DOM result
- The parse it from the generated DOM
- And, finally, use for validation

I don't think you can do it much better than that. JAXB's `schemagen` internal structures do not seem to be compatible with `javax.xml.validation.Schema`. So creating DOM and then parsing it back is the easiest way.

[Code example](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/blob/master/runtime/src/test/java/org/hisrc/xml/bind/tests/DynamicSchemaTest.java):

```
public class DynamicSchemaTest {

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class A {
        @XmlAttribute(required = true)
        public String name;

        public A() {
        }

        public A(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    @Test(expected = MarshalException.class)
    public void generatesAndUsesSchema() throws JAXBException, IOException,
            SAXException {
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(A.class);
        final DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
        result.setSystemId("schema.xsd");
        context.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {
            @Override
            public Result createOutput(String namespaceUri,
                    String suggestedFileName) {
                return result;
            }
        });

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        final SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
                .newInstance(WellKnownNamespace.XML_SCHEMA);
        final Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new DOMSource(result
                .getNode()));

        final Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setSchema(schema);
        // Works
        marshaller.marshal(new A("works"), System.out);
        // Fails
        marshaller.marshal(new A(null), System.out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, if you don't mind I have just a quick question, would it be better to use this approach than to load the XSD schema from the resource folder of my application?

Comment: I would definitely NOT do dynamic schema generation for validation. I'd generate the schema as resource in the compile time, it will serve for reference and contract purposes.